# Xcodebuild no such module

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to build an Xcode project through the terminal. My project uses a submodule called SwiftRichString which I'm importing in one of my files.

On my terminal, I tried:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj
```

But this says that it cannot find the module called SwiftRichString, as expected.

So then I tried,

```
xcodebuild -scheme SwiftRichString
```

This worked and said "Build Succeeded", but then if I try to do

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj
```

it fails just like before.

If I go to Xcode and go to Product>Scheme>SwiftRichString and build it, it succeeds building. Then if I build my project within Xcode, it works, but it doesn't build in terminal.